# scanner not found on debian

Tags: debian, printer, scanner, hp

I have Debian 10 with GNOME, and the printer/scanner is an HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M181fw.

I added this printer using the "graphical mode" (not using command lines).
The printer works. In the setup I see both printer and scanner but when I try to use the scanner the message "impossible to find the scanner" appears. (I don't know if the exact English translation is this one; I see the message in Italian.)

How can I use the scanner?

Comment: You need hplip. Check out https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip

Comment: I try to install it, and appear the message "error: debian-10.2 version is not supported, so all dependencies may not be installed. However trying to install using debian-10.0 version packages.". I try, and at the end there is the error "error: A required dependency 'pyqt4-dbus (PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4)' is still missing.
error: A required dependency 'pyqt4 (PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x))' is still missing.", so I search for these dependencies, but I can't find them, I found "python-qt4-dbus", so I've installed it, but doesn't work again

Comment: Sorry that's all the help I could be

Answer (score 0):

You need to install HP’s Linux Imaging and Printing software; in Debian, install the `hplip` package. [Your printer is supported by version 3.18.5](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/) or later of the package, and Debian 10 has version 3.18.12 which should work fine in your case.